# -init method doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I would normally paste my code, but I think in this case it's important to show how my code use to look.

I've made some changes, following an advice here to workaround a leak. However, my `-init` method doesn't get called anymore. Can anyone point out the problem?

The breakpoint for `-init` is never met.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It isn't simply that the break points aren't on lines that get executed any more? Have you added new breakpoints since editing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `[super init]`; this will call the `init` implementation of the superclass.

Comment: The current code is on the left, sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: @Dennis, so I shouldn't be calling `[super init]` in initWithKeyPadType, what should I do instead ?

Comment: @Jules: just put the contents of the `init` method (without this `[super init]` stuff into the `if (self != nil)` part and then remove the `init` method, so that your class can be intialized with `initWithKeyPadType` only.